# Change folder name with the name between ( ) with powershell

Tags: powershell, rename, files-folders

I have a folder structure and in all the folders there is a part between ( ).
Like "folder example(12345)"
Now I must rename all the folders with the name that is between ( ).
So the result is folder "12345"

I have an beginning and then I am stuck.

```
# Root path
$RootPath = "E:\Test\"
# Rename folders 
Get-ChildItem -Path $RootPath -Filter '*()*' -Directory -Depth 0 | Rename-Item -NewName
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on the answer of Saaru Lindestøkke I can confirm that the script should be working fine.

Here is the code that worked for me:

```
# Root path
$RootPath = "C:\Temp\"
# Rename folders 
Get-ChildItem -Path $RootPath -Filter '*(*)*' | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '.*\((.+?)\).*', '$1' }
```

I took your example, changed

```
*()*
```

to

```
*(*)*
```

otherwise it doesn't find anything since it looks for Wildcard()Wildcard and I also changed $RootPath to "C:\TEMP" (It works both with and without \ after TEMP) and only ran the part of Get-ChildItem to see the result. It would always find the folder(s) I created.

I removed as well "-Directory -Depth 0" since I didn't know if it was needed but never the less it should be working.

Comment: Thank you Guys.

Comment: No Problem. ;) @Robert

Answer (score 1):

This command will rename `folder example(12345)` to `12345`:

```
# Root path
$RootPath = "E:\Test\"
# Rename folders
Get-ChildItem -Path $RootPath -Filter '*(*)*' -Directory -Depth 0 | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace '.*\((.+?)\).*', '$1' }
```

What the rename command does:

```
Get-ChildItem            Get items in the folder
    -Path $RootPath      specified in this variable.
    -Filter '*(*)*'      Only take items that match this search
    -Directory           Only take directories
    -Depth 0             Only look in the current directory level
    |                    Forward the result to the next command
    Rename-Item          Rename the incoming items
    -NewName             Specify what the new name should be
    { 
        $_.Name          Take the name of the item to be renamed
        -replace         replace that name
        '.*\((.+?)\).*', matching a regular expression
        '$1'             with the first capture group (see below for more explanation)
    }
```

The regex can be further explained:

```
.*    Match any character 0 or more times
\(    Match a literal left parenthesis
(.+?) Capture a group containing any character occurring more than once, but as few times as possible.
\)    Match a literal right parenthesis
.*    Match any character 0 or more times
```

The captured group can be reused by referring to it with `$1`.

A demonstration:

[image]

Comment: Thank you Saaru but it did't do anything. I did't get a error in powershell but the folter had the same name as before

Comment: Well, I can't look on your screen, so indicating what error you've got might be a first step.

Comment: Thank you Guys.