# Windows Explorer replace something in filename

Tags: windows, windows-explorer, mp3, music

I want to properly rename all my downloaded music files.
Most of them start with "download -" and after that comes the music file name. Is there a possibility to remove the "download -" from all the files without renaming them 1 by 1?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following `.bat` file will do it:

```
@echo off
setlocal enabledelayedexpansion 
for %%f in ("download - *.*") do (
  set var=%%f
  ren "!var!" "!var:download - =!"
)
```

For more information see
[How-to: Edit/Replace text within a Variable](https://ss64.com/nt/syntax-replace.html).

Answer (score 0):

Seems simple if you know how. It's not exactly the same but very similar. You can use a Powershell Script to get ride of the "download-" part.

```
# Root path
$RootPath = "C:\Temp\"
# Rename folders 
Get-ChildItem -Path $RootPath -Filter 'download -*' | Rename-Item -NewName { $_.Name -replace 'download -*', '' }
```

How it works is $RootPath defines your File location. In your case it would be something like: "C:\Users\Username\Downloads"

Next Get-ChildItem looks for a file with "download -" at the beginning of the filename and replaces it with nothing. In other words it removes that part.

Here is the previous post I based the script on.
[Previous Post](https://superuser.com/questions/1701689/change-folder-name-with-the-name-between-with-powershell/1701710?noredirect=1#comment2619481_1701710)